# Calling external python script in main script and run there

Tags: python, function, subprocess, call

## Objective:

when fun() is run it should insert the script of external.py in main_script.py and run like a single file.

## main_script.py

```
def fun():
    x1 = 60
    x2=80
    exec(open('second.py').read())
    return(z1,z2)

print(fun()) # should print value to z1 and z2;
```

## external_script.py

```
z1=x1+x2
z2=x1-x2
```

Comment: It depends. If you are in control of second.py, you can convert it to module and import it and run it. use of `exec` should be of last resort.

Answer (score 0):

**In Your main_script.py**

```
  from external import *
  return_val = fun()
```

*Files must be in same directory*